# Photoshop scaling screwed up after upgrading to 4K monitor

Tags: macos, display, resolution, adobe-photoshop

Running Mac OS 10.14.6 and Photoshop 21.2.3. I just switched from a 1920 x 1200 monitor to a 4K (16:9) monitor whose native resolution is 3840 x 2160. I have the Mac's display preferences set to simulate 2560 x 1440 — this makes the user interface the right size across programs.

The problem is that if I make a new document of 3840 x 2160, it appears significantly smaller than the screen - about 75% of the screen size when Photoshop is set to display at 100%. I work a lot with screen-only images, and I want Photoshop to display actual 100% when set to display at 100%.

When the new document is set to the scaled size of 2560 x 1440, it appears MUCH smaller than the screen.

How can I make Photoshop display 100% at 100%? I don't remember having to do anything special before I switched monitors.

TIA!

Comment: did you make sure that you have an appropriate dpi setting on Photoshop (dots per inch or pixels per inch)?

Comment: Ps reads 'retina' data natively so shouldn't need adjustment… however, I think [but cannot test], it depends on how the Mac recognises the screen in Displays prefs. If you get the new-style ["Larger text… default … more space"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp1rO.jpg) version of the panel, this should work. If you get the old style [drop menu with a list of resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwA7e.png) to choose from, it doesn't. I cannot test this theory as I don't have a single Mac in the building that will show the new-style pref.

Comment: @MatthewBarclay, yes, but my understanding is that dpi affects only print size. I'm looking for one Photoshop pixel to equal one screen pixel.

Comment: @Tetsujin, according to the System Information panel, the display is running at 5120 x 2880, but this exceeds the monitor's specified dimensions of 3840 x 2160, as given in the monitor's user guide. Furthermore, when I hook the monitor up to a Windows 10 machine, it defaults to 3840 x 2160 and doesn't offer anything finer. Mac OS 10.14.6 has the "new style" Displays panel, but the drop menu is available by holding the Option key. In the list, the highest available resolution is 3840 x 2160.

Comment: Hmm… something's reading the monitor's spec incorrectly & it would appear Ps is reacting to that. Might be cabling spec. Hard to tell without knowing what connections/display/Mac.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I got the answer from Stephane Madrau, the developer of SwitchResX, a display resolution utility. (I've bought it and recommend it.) Stephane pointed out that because I had set scaling to simulate 2560x1440 in System Preferences' Display panel, MacOS generated a 5120x2880 internal image, part of a process (hiDPI) that scales an interface to 200% so that each visible pixel uses 4 subpixels. Photoshop then sees that 5120x2880 video signal in memory, and interprets it as the true resolution of the monitor. Long story short: use the true resolution when using Photoshop!

Comment: Ah...  nice find!